# Misbehaving Integral Function

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I am trying to evaluate a function, f(x,y) on a grid of 100x100 points. The function is a numerical integral. However, after evaluating the function at these points, and then plotting (`plt.contourf`), I get a peculiar result. I suspect the integration may be the cause, but this behavior is quite unexpected so I can't be sure. The integral is evaluated via `scipy.integrate.quad(lambda s: f(s,x,y),0,np.Inf)` with a nested for loop stepping over the x and y coordinates (no meshgrids)

[image]

The solid blue line is what I expect my function to evaluate too. Clearly, it is getting the shape correct, but there is something suspicious going on; I can't explain the sawtooth behavior. The points are evenly spaced in log space.

I can show more details of the function if that might help. Any ideas what's going on here? Are there other numerical integration techniques that might be better? I tried quadpy, but it gave the same result, which is probably expected. Would also appreciate any ideas on how to investigate this further

I also plotted the function f(x,y), along 1D, and the wiggles appear to only be along one axis. i.e.
[image]

versus

[image]

Thanks for reading, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your function and integral appear to be tiny. I suspect you're seeing roundoff error in your model. Perhaps rescale the problem such that most quantities are order 1?

Comment: Yes, I think this is turning out to be the issue @Nachiket. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use a Riemann sum that you code numerically so that you can tweak the dx, dy ...

I am sorry I don't have enough reputation to write this as a comment.